# Can Hammerheads both swim and fly?

Tags: zoids

in *Zoids: Chaotic Century* we see both Reese and Thomas pilot a Hammerhead underwater, Reese at the Sunken Zoidian Ruins and Thomas when defending the Ultrasaurus.

However we see that the Hammerhead that transported the Republican President, Louise Camford, (later hijacked by Hiltz) was in the air.

Does this mean Hammerheads can both swim and fly were in Reese's and Thomas's could have went airborn?